# Gaussian mixture model in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, gmm

I have gone through the link https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html regarding fitting a GMM in pyspark. I have carried out the same operation successfully in python, but after several iteration, I am unable to run in pyspark.

The questions i have are as follow;
1. The link mentioned above & another example of fitting GMM in pyspark I checked, takes a txt file with no column headings. I have a csv with 17 columns. The code is,

```
data = sc.textFile("..path/mydata.csv")
parsedData = data.map(lambda line: array([float(x) for x in line.strip().split(' ')]))
```

This worked, but when i am trying to fit `GaussianMixture.train` specifying some components, It is not working.

2. If the data used in the examples have no column headings, how can I judge which column is coming from which distribution & how the change in pattern is appearing?
3. How can I get heat-map from here so that whenever a new data comes in, I will use my trained model's heat-map to judge the distribution pattern of my new test data & can point out the mis-matches.

Thanks.